# Как удалить строки, начинающихся с

Tags: строки

Есть сайт, в нем заражены все js файлы.
Во всех js файлах есть вредоносный код, строки, начинающиеся с `"try{q=document.createElement"`

Есть ли программы, которые просканируют все файлы и удалят эти строки, начало которых такое? Антивирусы файлы просто удаляют, но они нужны для работы.

Comment: если есть консоль, то sed/awk. Если нет, то кто мешает написать скрипт (пусть даже на php), который все подчистит.

Если есть возможность/желание все скачать себе локально, тогда любым адекватным редактором, который может делать поиск+замену по файлам. К примеру `Notepad++` и другие подобные.

Comment: Вообще-то надо держать правильную копию сайта локально, и при всяческих проблемах просто копировать чистую копию на сервер.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выполните в корневой директории со скриптами команду:

```
find . -name \*.js | xargs sed -i "/^try{q=document\.createElement/d"
```

Comment: Супер, это помогло. Однако снять ответ предыдущий и сделать правильным этот не могу, не получаетя :(

Comment: @butteff, вы сначала нажмите на зеленую галочку возле принятого ответа, а потом поставьте на мой. Вроде работает так.

Comment: Почему-то не убирается.

Answer (score 1):

писал для своего сайта такой скрипт, вроде бы помогло.
Только сделайте для начала бекап своего сайта. И еще одно ограниxение: если файлов очень много то скрипт лучше применять несколько раз для отдельных папок.
Чтобы указать папку надо изменить переменную $dir

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

$dir = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] ;

cleanDir($dir);

function cleanDir($location){

    if ($handle = opendir($location)) {
        echo "Директория: $handle<br />";
        echo "Содержимое:<br />";

        while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
            if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
                if(is_dir ($location.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$entry)){
                    print '<span style="background-color:#ddd;">'.$location.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$entry."</span><br />";
                    cleanDir($location.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$entry);
                }else{

                    if(pathinfo($entry, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)=='js'){
                        $c = false;
                        $c = clearFile($location.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$entry);
                        if($c){
                            print '<span style="background-color:red;">VIRUS</span><span style="background-color:#fff;margin-left:20px;">'.$location.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$entry."</span><br />";
                        }else{
                            print '<span style="background-color:green;">CLEAR</span><span style="background-color:#fff;margin-left:20px;">'.$location.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR .$entry."</span><br />";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }else{
        print "Error !";
        die();
    }

}

function clearFile($path){

    $cont = file_get_contents($path);

    $pos = strrpos($cont,'try{q=document.createElement("d"+"i"+"v");q.appendChild(q+"");}');

    if($pos){
        $cont = substr($cont,0,$pos);
        file_put_contents($path,$cont);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```